# Drupal as a RestAPI

Tags: 7, bootstrapping

I have been using Drupal for a while to build medium to large CMS systems; love it.  From time to time I have to build a RestAPI.  Usually I use either Laravel, Lumen or Slim.  The only reason why I don't use Drupal is because the bootstrap / overhead is so high in Drupal.

What can be done to make this bootstrap / overhead less.  I fully understand that we will never get to the same lean and mean footprint that you get from a dedicated RestAPI framework - but surely we can make the bootstrap faster / smaller / quicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In drupal 7 you can use a contrib module called services, this will help you expose json by default for all nodes. You can also output main from hook_menu.

If you use laravel you may be more comfortable drupal 8, its built on symfony and supports test out of the box

Comment: Good suggestion; need an excuse to get into D8

Comment: No problem. Drupal 8 is really good. Way much more like Laravel. Please could you mark an answer as correct?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the speed costs to Drupal (beyond php as a language) are from the render layer.

If using Drupal just as a RESTful api, having fewer modules enabled (i.e. Views plugins) will likely cut down on your costs.

Having said that, in non-trivial use cases, I have to imagine the bootstrap is a much smaller performance hit relative to DB queries.

Comment: Thanks - I think that is fair enough.  Guess best would be to give it a try with a simple API and then bench-mark.

Comment: I'd sort of be interested in seeing the results, but I'm too lazy to test the differences. Also, I don't know what the differences are between Drupal 8 and 7 in regards to the performance.

Comment: I will 'book-mark' this question and if I get the chance to benchmark the 3 on a small API I will post my results.